# Nod32 causing LocalHost (ASP.NET Development Server) "Connection Interrupted" Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, localhost, nod32

I'm quoting myself on a previous question I asked to further explain:

*"I'm trying to run a freshly created ASP.NET Website using C#, however when I do so it launches FireFox and attempts to connect to http://localhost:1295/WebSite1/Default.aspx (for example), but after about 10-15 seconds it displays a "Connection Interrupted - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." Error.
This issue is also present with older ASP.NET C# pages/Web Services I've built in the past, nothing is actually running off the ASP.NET Development server."*

This is the problem that was occuring, that is before I noticed every time I ran the website, the notification for the ASP.NET Server-startup showed one port (1130 for example), and when the website failed to load; it turns out it was attempting to load the site on another port (In this case, 1128). It was suggested that an anti-virus program could have caused this kind of redirection; low and behold uninstalling Nod32 fixed the problem!

So my question is: Has anyone found a way to create an exception or remove this functionality from Nod32?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within Nod32 enter the Advanced Setup options, and turn off protocol filtering.

Comment: With NOD32 v3.0.650.0, for Protocol Filtering, I changed from "Ports and applications marked as Internet browsers or email clients" to "HTTP and POP3 ports". This fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known problem with NOD32. Looks like it's IMON module (protocol filter) accidentally does some modifications of TCP packets that go through it.

The solution is to either turn it off, or use a different software.