# Running a simple .NET web page

Tags: .net, browser

I create a simple project in .NET and this is what I get when I try to run the program. This is the URL that is being generated. Everythig was running and all of a sudden I am getting this issue. What might be the problem here. I am running firefox but doensn't work in IE7 either. I can access other site with no problem just when I try to test locally I get this error.

> http://www.localhost.com:49253/SimpleTest/
>
> **The connection was reset**
>
> The connection to the server was reset
>   while the page was loading.
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
>           connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make
>     sure
>           that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: Thank you all for your input so far. This is a pretty annoying problem.
Now I know for sure that something happened in my development machine. I submit the test project to my server and runs with no problem. It seems that something die in VS that's preventing to render a simple webpage. As soon as I find the problem based in all your inputs I'll let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just going back to Visual Studio/Visual Web Developer and restarting the development server? (i.e. Start without debugging/View page/ or whatever its called in VWD).  Or even exiting and restarting VS?

It could be the development server has just died for some strange reason.

EDIT: If you can't get the ASP.NET development server to restart could one of these be the problem?:

- [Nod32 causing LocalHost (ASP.NET Development Server) “Connection Interrupted” Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286356/nod32-causing-localhost-asp-net-development-server-connection-interrupted-pro)
- [The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading while uploading image to the server.](http://forums.asp.net/p/1104566/1686602.aspx)

EDIT (again): a couple more things to try:

- [Troubleshooting the ASP.NET Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w566a94d.aspx)
- [How to: Specify a Port for the ASP.NET Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I am sorry but how do I do that? I don't this I have checked that before.

Comment: In Visual Studio, in the Solution Explorer, right click on the page you want to see and click 'View in Browser'.   If the ASP.NET development server has died for some reason, you should see a new one pop up in your system tray with a little notification bubble.  If that doesn't work, reboot your machine and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL seems wrong, try this instead (without 'www' and '.com'):

http://localhost:49253/SimpleTest/

Comment: it's wrong because internet explorer automagically adds the 'www.' and '.com' if it can't find a functioning web server at the hostname 'localhost'

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
1) The url should be: http://localhost:49253/SimpleTest/ - you need to advise if the original was a typo.

2) To run the web app you need a running server - is this app launching if you hit run from within the IDE (what IDE are you using?). Visual Studio (from 2005) has a sort of integrated web server that you use for development, the application/pages won't work if this server isn't running.

3) To test external to the Visual Studio IDE you'll need to setup and configure IIS on your dev box or deploy the application to a system that has IIS installed and is configured with the appropriate .NET version

Comment: I am using the IDE for visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

By any chance do you have Eset Smart Security installed? I had this issue and it was solved by disabling Eset protocol filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can access port 49253?  Check that you can access it with the default port (80) first, you might have firewall issues.

Comment: well that port was generated automatically

Comment: I've had this problem before. For some reason, VS picked a port that wouldn't allow me to connect to it. I had to go into the project and manually set it to a different port

Answer (score 0):

You have a tray icon just near the computer clock that indicates web development server, where you can configure it, see if it is running etc.

Also you can go to your project properties and configure web development server - and see if you can adjust some configuration options - maybe some issues there.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure that you are not requiring HTTPS connections.  This is often done in the Application_BeginRequest event in Global.asax or as an http module.

If you are trying to run the site locally and do not have a certificate installed, and the site is doing a redirect to a secure url, then you will receive the messages you described.